# How to connect MySQL google collab jupiter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pymysql

Am trying to connect execute SQL query against MySQL DB using google collab Jupiter notebook by passing required host, DB, user,pwd, port details. Getting below error.

The SQL query was passed thru file while executing the query. please see the code below.

The same query was run successfully in local machine,getting issue while running the same query thru google collab Jupiter notebook with python script.

Before executing the query in the file, the drive was mounted successfully.

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my ip' (timed out)")

```
import pymysql
import pandas as PD

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='my ip',
    port=3306,
    user="root",
    passwd='Password',
    db="my db")

query = open('./SQLfile.sql', 'r')

# connection == the connection to your database, in your case prob_db
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(),conn)
df.tail(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, the modern version of Google Collab seems to support sqlalchemy, but not pymysql.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry I think it is somehow delayed answer but maybe help anyone it should be password, not passwd. If the problem still occurs please ensure this IP have the permission to access the database

Comment: It looks like db permissions, but answers should be more precise.